# Java arrays with names, surnames etc

Tags: arrays

I'm currently working on a program working as a banking system. I want to generate a lot of users with unique names, surnames. I want these to be random, so I am looking for a thing like an array that contains real names or surnames. Does anyone know a place, maybe a website, where I could find this type of data?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Willem - Yeah, I've seen websites like this one, the problem is that i am looking for a way to make a list of these names easier to implement to code, especialy Java. I was looking for a list of names formatted like this: `"Aaren", "Aarika", "Abagel" (...)`

Answer (score 1):

Actually has nothing to do with java itself, I find your Tags not to be appropriate.

Though, google "random names text file" and you'll get results like this
https://github.com/dominictarr/random-name/blob/master/first-names.txt

Comment: I've seen lists like this one, however, I wonder if there are ones that are already  formatted in a way that is quick and easy to implement to Java, for example like this:
|"Aaren", "Aarika", "Abagel" (...)|
If there aren't any "formatted" like this one, is there a way to quickly transform a list like the one in the link to a "formatted" one?

Comment: Maybe you should read about InputStream Classes. A comfortable one is the Scanner class. As well I would advice to use list instead of array since it can be extended easily.

https://www.java67.com/2012/11/how-to-read-file-in-java-using-scanner-example.html

Sorry couldn't insert my own code here so I hope this link helps.
Though actually this is not ontopic anymore.
If your origin question where to get your info is obsolete please mark the above answer as correct.
Cheers!